# calculating pi with monte carlo and while loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, montecarlo, pi

trying to calculate pi using this while loop but can not figure out how to stop it once it hits 3.14, it just keeps going infinitely

```
import turtle
import math
import random

t = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setworldcoordinates(-400,-400,400,400)

t.pu()
t.speed(0)
t.goto(0,-400)
t.pd()
t.color("blue")
t.circle(400)
t.color("orange")
hits=0.0
numdarts =0
eps=0.01
actPi=3.1415
estPi=3
error=abs(actPi-estPi)



while abs(error) >= eps:

    randx=random.uniform(-1,1)
    randy=random.uniform(-1,1)
    if (randx**2+ randy**2)<1:
        hits+=1.0
    numdarts+=1
    estPi=(hits/numdarts)
    error=abs(actPi-estPi)
    t.pu()
    t.goto(400*randx,400*randy)
    t.pd()
    t.dot()


print 4*(hits/numdarts)
wn.exitonclick()
```

i dont know how to get the loop to stop at 3.14

Comment: Is the value of error actually shrinking to be `< eps`? Your loop should exit when that happens, unless there's a syntax error or something I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your [method of calculating pi should converge to pi/4](http://www.thephysicsmill.com/2014/05/03/throwing-darts-pi/). you need to multiply estPi by 4:

```
estPi = 4*hits/numdarts
```

EDIT: I just saw that you consider that in the last print! I think you just forgot to add it when computing the error :)

Comment: thank you that fixed the loop now it is finishing as i wanted it to